How to keep the same session ID in the Redis Store with Socket.IO?
I have a little problem there, upon first connection, I create a new session on the server and store that in the Redis store, send it back to the client which stores it in the local storage.
During the next connection, it appears that it is reloading the same session id just fine, however, yet, in the Redis somehow a new session ID is still being generated. Anyone have clue what I messed up? I want to keep the same session ID and not always generate a new one.
As you can see the server wise looks great, but for whatever reason the Redis keep having new sessions stored.
024-09-07T20:47:22+02:00 PagerCast: DEBUG: Session reloaded with ID: 79c7049a-e032-4958-82a6-76a37880c478
2024-09-07T20:47:27+02:00 PagerCast: INFO: User disconnected
2024-09-07T20:47:28+02:00 PagerCast: INFO: Client session ID: 79c7049a-e032-4958-82a6-76a37880c478
2024-09-07T20:47:28+02:00 PagerCast: INFO: Handling behavior for version 0.1
2024-09-07T20:47:28+02:00 PagerCast: DEBUG: Session reloaded with ID: 79c7049a-e032-4958-82a6-76a37880c478

I do appreciate any help or highlight!
    function createNewSession(socket) {
      const newSessionId = uuidv4();
      logger.debug(`Creating new session with ID: ${newSessionId}`);
    
      const newSession = {
        id: newSessionId,
        cookie: { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 72 * 60 * 60 * 1000) }, // 72 hours
      };
    
      socket.request.sessionStore.set(newSessionId, newSession, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          logger.error('Error saving new session to Redis:', err);
        } else {
          logger.debug(`New session successfully saved to Redis with ID: ${newSessionId}`);
          socket.emit('session', { sessionId: newSessionId });
        }
      });
    
      socket.data.sessionId = newSessionId;
    }
    
    
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      const clientSessionId = socket.handshake.query.sessionId;
      logger.info(`Client session ID: ${clientSessionId}`);
    
      if (clientSessionId) {
        socket.request.sessionStore.get(clientSessionId, (err, session) => {
          if (err) {
            logger.error('Session retrieval error:', err);
          } else if (session && session.id) {
            const newSession = { ...session };
            delete newSession.id;
    
            Object.assign(socket.request.session, newSession);
            logger.debug(`Session reloaded with ID: ${clientSessionId}`);
    
            socket.request.session.save((err) => {
              if (err) {
                logger.error('Session save error:', err);
              } else {
                socket.emit('session', { sessionId: clientSessionId });
              }
            });
    
            socket.data.sessionId = clientSessionId;
          } else {
            logger.debug('Session not found, generating new session ID');
            createNewSession(socket);
          }
        });
      } else {
        logger.debug('No session ID provided, generating new session');
        createNewSession(socket);
      }

